# How to prove that the sign of the all eigenvalues of $AD$ are always the same as that of $BD$?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, similar-matrices

$A$ is a similar matrix of $B$, all eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ are positive, $D$ is a positive semi-definite diagonal matrix. How to prove that the sign of all eigenvalues of $AD$ is always the same as that of $BD$?

For simplicity, we assume that $D$ is a diagonal matrix with $0$ or $1$ diagonal elements. I've done 100000 experiments and it's always true i.e. $AD$ always has the same numbers of positive eigenvalues as $BD$.

Comment: What exactly is the statement? That the product of all of the eigenvalues of the two matrices has the same sign? That the two matrices have the same numbers of positive eigenvalues? That the two matrices have the same eigenvectors and the corresponding eigenvalues have the same signs?

Comment: I mean that the two matrices have the same numbers of positive eigenvalues and also have the same numbers of non-positive eigenvalues.

Answer (score 3):

This is false: Take $$A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}2&0\\ 0&-1\end{array}\right],D=\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\ 0&0\end{array}\right],~{\rm and~}B=\left[\begin{array}{cc}-1&0\\ 0&2\end{array}\right]=P^{-1}AP,$$ where $$P=\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\ 1&0\end{array}\right].$$ Then $$AD=\left[\begin{array}{cc}2&0\\ 0&0\end{array}\right],BD=\left[\begin{array}{cc}-1&0\\ 0&0\end{array}\right].$$

**[EDIT]** The result is still false if one requires that all the eigenvalues are positive. Take $$A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\ 0&2\end{array}\right],D=\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\ 0&4\end{array}\right],~{\rm and~}B=\left[\begin{array}{cc}6&4\\ -5&-3\end{array}\right]=P^{-1}AP,$$ where $$P=\left[\begin{array}{cc}-5&-5\\ -5&-4\end{array}\right].$$ Then $$AD=\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\ 0&8\end{array}\right],BD=\left[\begin{array}{cc}6&16\\ -5&-12\end{array}\right],$$ where $BD$ has eigenvalues $\{-2,-4\}.$

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. I may need to modify my question. Actually, all eigenvalues of A and B should be positive values.

Comment: @Harry Please see my edits.

Comment: Thank you. Let me check my settings in experiments.